# Fill an array with random names

Tags: python, arrays, random, generated

How to create a list named "names" and fill it with randomly generated names (the names don't have  to exist, and could be like "asdddds", "asdasd")

I want to make a massive array with this, like `names[1000000000]`, but I have no clue about how to generate the names and how to fill the list with these names.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? It would be a great project since you want to learn Python.

Answer (score 0):

```
import string
alpha = list(string.ascii_lowercase)# You can also use string.ascii_uppercase
name = []
for _ in range(100): # For getting 100 Names
    name.append(''.join(random.choices(alpha,k=random.randint(5,10)))) # Here 5 & 10 are lower and upper limit of size name
```

Comment: hi Yash, i am getting an error :

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xxxxx/random_names.py", line 5, in <module>
    name.append(''.join(random.choices(alpha,k=random.randint(5,10)))) # Here 5 & 10 are lower and upper limit of size name
NameError: name 'random' is not defined

Comment: Sorry my mistake you should include `import random`